# Can someone help me fix this macro code? All gravy, except for resizing pane

Tags: microsoft-word, macros

I am trying to make a macro to open and resize navigation styles panes automatically on open (globally). I can get it to work, except the resizing of the styles pane. Unfortunately, copying the code that resizes the nav pane to the style pane doesn't work :(  [You can see the section it highlights and the error message here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iE1eO.png). Can someone please help me to correct it.

```
Sub AutoOpen()

Call PaneFixNav
Call PaneFixStyle

End Sub

Sub PaneFixNav()

Application.CommandBars("Navigation").Visible = True
    Dim iWidth As Integer
    iWidth = 250
        With CommandBars("Navigation")
            .Width = iWidth
        End With

End Sub

Sub PaneFixStyle()

Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Visible = True
    Dim iWidth As Integer
    iWidth = 250
        With Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting)
            .Width = iWidth
        End With

End Sub
```

Ps. I have basically no experience with macros besides this, which I pieced together from different posts. So, sorry for what might well be a dumb question.

Comment: .Width isn't a property of the TaskPanes object. You only have Application, Creator, Parent or Visible properties to set/get. Try `Application.TaskPanes(wdTaskPaneFormatting).Application.Width = iWidth`

Comment: Thanks... but I still can't get it to work. Does that replace everything I had previously under 'Sub PaneFixStyle()'? If so, where does the visible command fit?

Comment: It appears there is simply no way to do this, at least from VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the built-in dock-able task panes of Microsoft Word cannot be resized programmatically.

With VBA, only custom modal and non-modal user forms (dialogs) can be resized at runtime.